# Question about linear components.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Consider two broken lines $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $L_{1} \cap L_{2} = \emptyset$ (broken line is set of $A_{i}$ and $[A_{i}A_{i+1}]$ for $i = 0 \dots m-1$). Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus (L_{1} \cup L_{2})$ is connected component (there is a continue curve , which connect any two points).

I know that's obvious, but how proof should looks using $\epsilon $ and $\delta$. My idea was : let $\epsilon = p(L_{1},L_{2})$ and let's make a cover around them, now we could get some points in this cover and connect any two points. But is it strictly proof or no?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb R^2-L_1 \cup L_2$?

Comment: @AndresMejia yes, thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of a broken line?

Comment: @freakish add definition in question

Comment: @rschwieb first case

Comment: If you remove two disjoint triangles from the plane, don't they disconnect the plane into $3$ open regions? Maybe I don't understand exactly the definition you are using.

Comment: "Connected component"?

Comment: @rschwieb I mean they have no intersection , just two simple broken lines without intersections.

Comment: You mean the broken lines also do not self -intersect?

Comment: @rschwieb yes, my bad forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0):

First, let us call the broken lines *piecewise linear, nonintersecting curves*. Seconde, it does not matter how many of those you have. The same argument works with 1 curve as well as with 10 curves.

Consider two points in the plane and connect them by the straight line. If the line does not intersect your curve, you are done. If it does intersect your curve, it will do so only finitely many times. The straight line may coincide with a segment of your piecewise linear curve, but even then there will be finitely many times it enters and leaves the curve. For each of those intersection points, modify the straight line by *guiding it around* the piecewise linear curve. Because all piecewise linear curves are compact and do not intersect, they will have a strictly positive distance from each other. So you can guide the path around the piecewise linear curve, without having to worry that you will encounter one of the other piecewise linear curves.

This argument should become much clearer by drawing a picture. Words get you only that far. And $\epsilon$-$\delta$ in this case can only lead to obfuscation.

Comment: Hm, I understand that it's work , but , that's not a formal solution. It's obvious that we can go around lines , or walk close to lines.

Comment: No, it is not, but if needed, this argument can be made into a formal solution. It is possible to write down a formula for "going around lines". And compactness will tell you how close you have to stay to the line in order not to encounter other lines.

Comment: but actually that's not point of my question

Comment: Then I must admit that I misunderstood the point of your question.

Comment: I'm interested in $\epsilon - \delta$ solution. Because it's evident that we can draw the curve